# JQuery - Problem with Modal Dialog after reload page in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

take a look to the example:

example.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Button1').button().click(function() {
      $("#mainContent").load("example_1.jsp");
    });
  });
</script>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="RELOAD" />
<div id="mainContent"></div>
```

example_1.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#a").button().click(function() {
      $("#a_form").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#a_form").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 480,
      width: 625,
      modal: true
    });
  });
</script>

<input id="a" type="button" value="MODAL" />
<div id="a_form" title="Modal Dialog" class="ui-widget">
  Hello!
</div>
```

I load example.jsp and I press the button "RELOAD".
Then, in "mainContent", appears the button "MODAL", that open a modal dialog.

But if I press again "RELOAD" button and then "MODAL" the MODAL DIALOG doesn't appear anymore!
why? 
where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because :

`<input id="a" type="button" value="MODAL" />`

Is using an ID.

When you run load again you are creating another input with the `id=a` which is not allowed.

Try using a class identifier instead of an id

Comment: also "a_form" must be called with class identifier, otherwise 2 modal dialog show up: $(".a_form").dialog("open");

Comment: and what about if I insert a JQGrid in the Modal Dialog? after reload, the grid remains empty! in the button.click function I've added $(".a_grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:"json"}).trigger("reloadGrid"); just before $(".a_form").dialog("open"); any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because the script block of example_1 is ignored because it is loaded dynamically into the page.

So what you need to do is to move that script block to example.jsp and use .live() for '#a' instead of .click()

```
$("#a").button().live("click", function() {
  $("#a_form").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you load/reload the main content try to empty it and then load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Button1').button().click(function() {
      $("#mainContent").html('').load("example_1.jsp");
    });
  });
</script>
```